# Trying to setup live magento website to localhost

Tags: magento

My Magento live site is working fine. I wanted to setup it locally.
First I downloaded the project folder and database, then I installed the database and extracted files and put it into the folder which is in htdocs.
After that I changed the local.xml file (which is in app->etc->local.xml),
then I changed the secure/base_url and unsecure/base_url 
but, it gives error:

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table i checked my
>   both databse live and local , both are same.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot write comments.

Are you sure about name and user of database in local.xml? Please check again.

Answer (score 0):

**It may be due to the following reasons:-**

**1-**  suppose i'm taking local domain as localhost & under the htdocs folder i'm taking magento
folder.

so my live project will be in the directory http://localhost/magento/
you should set http://localhost/magento/  in secure/base_url and unsecure/base_url in core_config_data table & make sure that there won't be any pre or post spaces in the url http://localhost/magento/

**2-** check properly app/etc/local.xml for the correct uname,password & db name(it shouldn't contain any space & should be localhost details).

**3-** Rename cache folder(e.g-cache++) which is under var/cache directory(on localhost).

**4-** check local.xml permission, it should be 0644.

**5-** some files may be miss or your live db not exported properly.

**6-** rename .htaccess(if it contains some custom coding) & place a fresh .htaccess of the same version.

**7-** make sure that ther won't be any wrong rename local.xml file under app/etc/ directory sometimes we rename as local_test.xml which is not
standard way. it should be renamed like local.xml++ or local.xml_test.

Hope it'll help you!!!